# What do I not understand about APIs?

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology

**Wikipedia definition:**

In computer programming, an application programming interface (API) specifies how some software components should interact with each other.

I've seen some people consider an api of a library just as documentation. Like on api.jquery.com they show how the jquery library gets used. I've also seen people define an api as the **visible parts** of a library.

I understand how web api's work: There's an interface which you can use to interact with a webapplication using JSON or XML, e.g. youtube api. So I could get information about a youtube video or playlist.

I've read that there are different types of api's. Web api's, library api's, OS api's etc.

Here are some examples that I hope I can clear my confusion with.

---

**Example 1**

If I'd include a library in C++, then the header files would be the API? What about an api like Win32/Winapi. Why is this called an api and not a library? Don't I just include it into my source code and start using it?

**Example 2**

If I want to use a library in C# I'd add a .DLL to my bin folder and tell the compiler I want to use the library (i.e. using System.Web). Would the api just be all the public members (hence the visible parts) in the class that is written in the library?

**Example 3**

Lets say company **X** has written an MMORPG game but they do not have a website api. I want to make a windows application and I'd like to make it possible to view any character within my app. How would I communicate with the game to get this data? Where is the api written? How can I view it?

---

And what kind of an api would an operating system have? How could I use it? Any examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**API is a contract between service provider and a service consumer** (your program). This is it. How is it done, it's implementation specific.

A contract in a way that provider agrees to "If you call function X with parameter Y I promise you the result will be Z.". But client also agrees to "call function X with parameter of type T" and not any nonsense.

Ad1: Your code is a library. It can implement many hidden functions, eg `void Nuke_hidden(double lat, double lon);` which can strike any place in the world. But you can choose to not expose this method. Instead, have some other one which takes an `enum` parameter limited to `New York, London, Moscow`.

Now how your code does something is the body of your library. What you **allow** your consumers to do with it, is part of your API. Your contract specifically allows bombing only those 3 cities, and forbids bombing any other place.

Ad2: You got it. Exactly.

Ad3: If someone doesn't expose and document an API, it's usually because they don't want you to write such program : ). However they must have some sort of API (even if they never call it such), which the client uses to communicate with the server.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a contract? To me a contract is an agreement between two party's, so in this context the service provider and consumer. But I cant grasp what a contract has to do with the visible parts of a library. 

Why is the windows api called an api and not a library?

Comment: @user1534664 First of all, an API can be implemented using more than one library (as it is the case with Windows). Secondly, a library can contain more functions than the actual API - they may be public or hidden. Third: An API doesn't need to be implemented using a library. For example: Ebay has an API, but you interact with a WEB server to use the API.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar The problem was that I was constantly trying to visualize what an API was, thinking it was some kind of object like a library, while in reality it's something abstract (hence a contract). Major thanks to you both.

Comment: @user1534664: You can replace the word `contract` with `trust`. It's trusting that the documentation is correct. Strictly speaking, without documentation a "thing" (whatever it is, be it http request or function call) cannot be called an API but is merely code.

Comment: @slebetman So you would say in the context of Ad3 in this answer, it is not an api since there is no documentation?

Comment: A protocol. An api is specifically an Application Programming Interface. If it's not documented then you can't really write a program for it.

Comment: @user1534664 I can create an API and not document it. Still it remains an API.

Comment: @user1534664 I'd say that an interface becomes an API when you give access to it for other people to use.

Comment: @Agent_L Yeah, that sounds more logical than it being an api once there's documentation of it.

Answer (score 2):

An API is just a definition how to interact with a software component. For example, an API for ebay could contain a function call to create an auction and a function call to retrieve all bids for an auction.

The API is neither some piece of software, nor the documentation, nor a DLL. The API is an abstract definition of how to "talk" to a piece of software. How it is implemented depends on the developer that provides the API.

Of course, to tell other programmers how to use your software, you need to provide documentation of the API. That is: What calls are available? Which parameters do they require and accept?

So, regarding example 1) The header file would define how to use your API using C++. Just like for Windows. Windows has an API (that is: an interface applications can use to create windows, textboxes, etc.). The header files define how to use that from C++.

Regarding example 2) A .NET DLL is a way for a piece of software to interact with an API from managed code. You *could* say that every class in C# defines an API in that it has public members.

Regarding example 3) Not every piece of software provides access to its internals to other software. For example: Word does have an API you can use to create add-ins. Other software does not provide such an API.